# How to get data from multiple lines and append as columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, outliers

After some consideration, I have decided to change the parameters of my question.

I have really big csv file (over 300 thousand lines) which spans 3 years.

The file is set up as shown below, where all of the companies are under one column and their electrical usage is in the same line but different column.

```
Date and time           Company      Usage
2020-01-01 00:00:00     Company1      300
2020-01-01 00:00:00     Company2      20
2020-01-01 00:00:00     Company3      120
2020-01-01 00:00:00     Company4      600
2020-01-01 01:00:00     Company1      450
2020-01-01 01:00:00     Company3      80
2020-01-01 01:00:00     Company4      650
2020-01-01 02:00:00     Company1      350
2020-01-01 02:00:00     Company2      35
2020-01-01 02:00:00     Company3      150
2020-01-01 02:00:00     Company4      550
```

**Note: Fabricated numbers**

I am wondering how I can change the data in such a way that all of the companies are displayed as columns, as such

```
date and time          Company1     Company2     Company3
2020-01-01 00:00:00     300            20          120
2020-01-01 01:00:00     450            80          80
2020-01-01 02:00:00     350            35          150
```

I have tried `df.groupby('Company')['Usage']` which really didn't do much. I tried to make a for rule which didn't do anything (probably due to my very limited experience), similar to this

```
for i in df:
    for j in i:
        if df[][] = "date and time":
            newDf.append()
```

This is probably much easier than I think, but I haven't stumbled on the right answer for few days now.

Comment: Can you provide a larger sample of the data (or the full dataset)? Enough to see the outliers.

Comment: @mozway This is over 315 thousand lines of csv data. Plus each company has its own range, so I am not sure how I would do that. If I could do df['company1'].average or something similar, that would help very much.

Comment: I probably could open up the csv and make a pivot table and then read everything back in.... but then there are more files to  manage

Comment: Why are you interested in 4? Isn't 2 the outlier company since it has missing data? (assuming every company is reporting data per hour)

Comment: @olividir just one of the companies, 10% of the data, maybe with something to anonimize it, this shouldn't be too big. Coming up with a correct strategy without seeing the data is quite difficult...

Comment: @mozway I know, but the data is under NDA, I am not allowed to share it :(

Comment: @xprilion I am actually getting the data from the company running the grid. These companies are buyers of electricity. Some of these companies register once every few days or weeks depending on their environment.
I am interested in these 4 because they are large users and I am checking electric transportation restrictions in the system. And I already see those at those big 4.

Answer (score 0):

After long search, I found a solution. There are probably more, but for now this one works up to a point for me

```
new_df = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Company')))
```

At leas this is a step in the right direction.